# How to display map in flutter list view from firestore where key is user input

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an app that display map from firestore to flutter ListView but i am stuck at some point where data is coming from firestore but the problem is displaying data. it displays data in weird way.

i have put images below for better understanding, thank you,

[Firestore Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp5h7.png)

how it displays in device

[device output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj1cS.jpg)

here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ItemsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ItemsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ItemsPage> createState() => _ItemsPageState();
}

class _ItemsPageState extends State<ItemsPage> {
  final String documentId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!
      .uid; // Replace with the document ID you want to read
  final CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('items'); // Replace with your collection name

  TextEditingController itemNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController totalItemController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController availableItemController = TextEditingController();

  Map<String, dynamic>? documentData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readDocument();
  }

  void addItem(String itemName, int totalItems, int availableItems) async {
    try {
      DocumentReference documentReference = collectionReference.doc(documentId);

      await documentReference.update({
        itemName: {
          'itemName': itemName,
          'totalItems': totalItems,
          'availableItems': availableItems
        },
      });
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('object');
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> readDocument() async {
    try {
      DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
          await collectionReference.doc(documentId).get();

      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        setState(() {
          documentData = documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;
        });
      } else {
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('object');
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: collectionReference.doc(documentId).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"));
          }

          if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data!.exists) {
            return const Center(child: Text("Document does not exist."));
          }

          Map<String, dynamic> documentData =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

          List<MapEntry<String, dynamic>> fieldData =
              documentData.entries.toList();

          return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      // margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                      height: 60,
                      width: 100,
                      child: Center(
                        child:
                            Text('ITEM', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const VerticalDivider(
                      thickness: 5,
                      width: 2,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      // margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 10, 0),
                      height: 50,
                      width: 100,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text('qty'.toUpperCase(),
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      // margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 10, 0),
                      height: 60,
                      width: 100,

                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                             'available',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: fieldData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      String key = fieldData[index].key;
                      dynamic value = fieldData[index].value;

                      return Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                            height: 60,
                            width: 100,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(key,
                                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 10, 0),
                            height: 60,
                            width: 100,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                value.toString(),
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 10, 0),
                            height: 60,
                            width: 100,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                value.toString(),
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 20, 8, 20),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: itemNameController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Item Name',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0, 8, 20),
                      child: TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        controller: totalItemController,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Total Items',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0, 8, 20),
                      child: TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        controller: availableItemController,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Available Items',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
                      height: 60,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              addItem(
                                  itemNameController.text,
                                  int.parse(totalItemController.text),
                                  int.parse(availableItemController.text));
                              itemNameController.clear();
                              totalItemController.clear();
                              availableItemController.clear();
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            });
                          },
                          child: Text('Add Items'.toUpperCase())),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i have been trying to solve problem for many days but not getting desired result,

i have also tried to use chatGPT but did not get any result.